# MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

I have Mysql query problem. My query is

```
UPDATE oc_product p 
INNER JOIN oc_currency as c 
ON p.price2_currency_code=c.`code` 
SET p.price=CASE WHEN p.price2_currency_code='EUR' THEN p.price2*c.`value` 
WHEN p.price2_currency_code='USD' THEN p.price2*c.`value` 
ELSE p.price;
```

I am getting always

> [Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near '' at line 4

Comment: Are you missing an End Case ?

Comment: I missed END case Thansk @Mort

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be you missed the `END`

```
UPDATE oc_product p 
INNER JOIN oc_currency as c 
ON p.price2_currency_code=c.`code` 
SET p.price=CASE WHEN p.price2_currency_code='EUR' THEN p.price2*c.`value` 
WHEN p.price2_currency_code='USD' THEN p.price2*c.`value` 
ELSE p.price
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following query:

```
update p
set p.price = (case when p.price2_currency_code='EUR' 
then p.price2*c.`value` 
when p.price2_currency_code='USD' then p.price2*c.`value` 
else p.price end)
from oc_product p
join oc_currency c
on p.price2_currency_code=c.`code`;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "
    UPDATE oc_product AS p
    INNER JOIN oc_currency as c
    ON p.price2_currency_code=c.`code`
    SET p.price=case WHEN p.price2_currency_code='EUR' THEN p.price2*c.`value`
    WHEN p.price2_currency_code='USD' THEN p.price2*c.`value`
    ELSE p.price
    END";
```

Answer (score 0):

You have only two conditions so you can also use an `IF` which is simpler than the `CASE`

```
UPDATE oc_product p 
    INNER JOIN oc_currency as c 
    ON p.price2_currency_code=c.`code` 
SET p.price=
    IF(p.price2_currency_code='EUR' OR p.price2_currency_code='USD', p.price2*c.`value`, p.price);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an END CASE in end of your query and you are all set.

```
UPDATE oc_product p 
INNER JOIN oc_currency as c 
ON p.price2_currency_code=c.`code` 
SET p.price=CASE WHEN p.price2_currency_code='EUR' THEN p.price2*c.`value` 
WHEN p.price2_currency_code='USD' THEN p.price2*c.`value` 
ELSE p.price
END CASE;
```